# How to set up CORS and JWT token validation with ExpressJs based on website

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, cors, middleware

So basically, I have two websites with different subdomain. The first one doesn't need JWT Token validation but the second needs validation.

How to use the `app.use(authorization)` only when the origin is `https://app.website.com` ?

```
import cors from 'cors';

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  app.use(cors());
} else {
  const whitelist = ['https://www.website.com', 'https://app.website.com'];
  app.use(
    cors({
      origin: function (origin, callback) {
        if (origin && whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1) {
          return callback(null, true);
        }
        return callback(new Error('Forbidden'), false); 
      },
      optionsSuccessStatus: 204
    })
  );
  app.use(authorization);
}
```

JWT validation as a middleware, I tried to check `req.get('origin')` but it's undefined..

```
import admin from '../helpers/firebase.helper';

const authorization = async (
  req,
  res,
  next
): Promise<void> => {
  if (req.headers?.authorization?.startsWith('Bearer ')) {
       const idToken = req.headers.authorization.split('Bearer ')[1];
    try {
      const decodeToken = await admin.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken);
      req.current = decodeToken;
      next();
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(StatusCodes.UNAUTHORIZED).send('UnAuthorized');
    }
  } else {
    res.status(StatusCodes.UNAUTHORIZED).send('UnAuthorized');
  }
};
```

The first site `www.welcome.com` is built with Nextjs (server side rendering) and the second one with React create app (client side rendering). So when I check `req.get('origin')` for react create app request it's working fine, but for the request which comes from the nextjs app it's undefined.

Diagram
[image]

Comment: Have you tried doing `cors({ origin: true, credentials: true })`? But for that you'll need a server with SSL on. And make sure that your JWT cookie has the `sameSite: "none"` property on it

Comment: I tried but nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `req.hostname` to get the host on which you received the request. You can check other properties of the request object in the docs: http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req

Comment: Yes, I have the `req.hostname` but I don't know why it's equal to the server host. Maybe it's because my `www.website.com` is build with Nextjs (server side rendering)..

Comment: Hm, so maybe I misunderstood something. Do you have a backend which listens on two different subdomains? Or you have one backend and two different frontends on two different subdomains which call the same backend?

Comment: Ah so I have 2 frontends (nextjs, create react app) and 1 backend (expressjs). 2 frontends call the same backend and the frontends are subdomain `www` for nextjs and `app` for react. I created a diagram [link](https://imgur.com/QIGfKmP) to illustrate it.

Comment: Yeah, then the hostname is no use for you - I thought you have the backend on two domains. `req.hostname` should contain the host which is processing the request (the host which was called). Try checking the referer header, maybe it will contain proper caller information. It does look like the client from nextjs is not setting the origin header properly (but maybe it should be set by the browser? not sure about that)

Comment: Yes, I tried to check the referer header but it's undefined .. It's weird because when I check `req.host` is equal to backend URL for a nextjs request . So I think I have to configure something with nextjs.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I solved the problem. The problem was with NextJs, I was doing a server side request with `getserversideprops` (no CORS when server to server), so I move to a basic client request, then it's works fine. I have access to `req.origin` so I can check the origin.